# Template not saving 404 not found umbraco/RestServices/SaveFile/SaveTemplate UMBRACO

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

When I was trying to save the template, I can't able to save the template and also I didn't get any error message.
But in Chrome console I can able to see the following message "**404 not found umbraco/RestServices/SaveFile/SaveTemplate**".

In App_Data I was getting the following error,

```
ERROR Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.ScheduledPublishing - [Thread 5] An error occurred with the scheduled publishing System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request) at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data) at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(String address, String data) at Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.ScheduledPublishing.Run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a permissions issue? Check that the identity the website is running under has permissions to read/write/modify the views folder.

Comment: It has all the permissions.! And by the way, It happens only for a particular template which has a lot of content